# Why was this question asking "Was this inappropriate" reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is the question: [Was it inappropriate for me to wear a qipao as a formal dress?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13870/was-it-inappropriate-for-me-to-wear-a-qipao-as-a-formal-dress/)

It was closed originally as off-topic, but got reopened after [an edit](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/13870/revisions) which replaced "is this cultural appropriation" with "was this inappropriate / rude".

According to the [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (which is also explained in [this meta question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/is-it-rude-to-ask-if-its-rude-to-ask-or-what-to-do-with-questions-asking-I)), those types of questions are off-topic:

> This includes questions that:
>
> - ask us to adjudicate “right” and “wrong” in a situation or whether something is rude/racist/sexist/[insert other discriminatory terms]. If you are having a dispute with your spouse or coworker, we are not going to settle the dispute for you or give you points to argue. **Focus your question on resolving your issue, rather than whether there is an issue or not.**

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

In this question there is no indication that OP actually had an issue due to wearing the dress, so the only goal I can make out is validation.

Is there something I'm missing that makes this on topic? Why was this question reopened?

Comment: It has since been re-closed